# Spring Boot Application not changing

Tags: ajax, maven, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-tool-suite

I've done a project before. (https://github.com/sercandorman/CRUD-Operations-With-Spring) Now I wanted to go through it. When I add a html file into resources/templates, I can see the page. And in that page I'm trying to get data from mysql database. Meanwhile I tried to use same ajax/get method but faced 404 no messages found error. And I'm sure that Im using right RequestMapping and Thymeleaf  iterations. Already I've used before so I did same things but just from different table. I could not understand 'why'!? ...

Then I've tried changing the RequestMapping method(findAll) that was working before. AND NOTHING CHANGED. Method still running as old way ! I'm trying to broke it, but no, nothing happens. How it can be possible ?!

Note : I've tried to open project Spring Tool Suite and Netbeans. After facing tousands of error, successfuly opened project with STS but look at it. I can not change its original form.

Is this about war/jar files ?! What should I do ?

findAll method (Working)

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/findAll", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public void findAll() {
    mavIndex.addObject("allRecords", personService.findAll());
    mavIndex.addObject("mod", "VIEW_RECORDS");
}
```

with this ;

```
<div class="row" id="getResultDiv" th:switch="${mod}">
...
    <div th:case="VIEW_RECORDS">
...
        <tbody>
            <tr th:each="result : ${allRecords}">
                <td th:text="${result.id}" id="tid"></td>
                <td th:text="${result.name}" id="tname"></td>
                <td th:text="${result.surname}" id="tsurname"></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
     </div>
</div>
```

But when I do that;

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/lists", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public void findAllLists() {
    mavIndex2.addObject("allLists", listsService.findAllLists());
    mavIndex2.addObject("mod2", "VIEW_LISTS");
}
```

with this ;

```
...
<tbody>
    <tr th:each="res : ${allLists}">
        <td th:text="${res.listname}"></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Also I'm sure that Services and Repositories are same.

As I mentioned above, when I change /findAll method nothing changing and my /lists method not working.

What must I do ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm neither a Netbeans nor an STS expert but to rule out any problems which come from your IDEs you could try the following:

A complete rebuild and start of your project, so that any changes in Java or resource files have a chance to be reflected in your next server start:

`mvn clean spring-boot:run`

> Please make sure that you **stop all running servers** you started earlier.

Comment: Sir thank you sooo much. I wish I'd ask before. It worked. I love you !
Im just confused about 'Can not I use any IDE anymore for project that I import..?'

Comment: Hehe oh do love me too much I'm already married. ;-) Of course you still can use any IDE you want, I just wanted to emphasize, that I personally have no experiences in the both IDEs above, I am an IntelliJ user.

Comment: @SercanDorman you can use any IDE, you should just use your IDE's `import maven project' feature.